# Interface with generic type of the class implementing the interface?

Tags: kotlin

Having a class that implement a interface with generic type of "This" class

Is there a way to do this without a cast?

Simple code:

```
interface Triggerable<This: Triggerable<This>> {
    var trigger: (This) -> Unit
    fun triggerNow() = trigger(this as This)
}
class Test : Triggerable<Test>{
    override var trigger: (Test) -> Unit = { /*...*/ }
}
```

The same a little more complex:

```
interface TriggerInterface<T> {
    val trigger: (T) -> Unit
    fun triggerNow()
}
interface Triggerable<T: Triggerable<T>>: TriggerInterface<T> {
    override fun triggerNow() = trigger(this as T)
}
interface Signalable<T>: TriggerInterface<T> {
    var value: T
    override fun triggerNow() = trigger(value)
}
class Test : Triggerable<Test>{
    override val trigger: (Test) -> Unit = { /*...*/ }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be possible like this

```
 interface TriggerInterface<T: TriggerInterface<T>> {
    val trigger: (T) -> Unit
    fun triggerNow()

    fun getThis(): T
 }

 interface Triggerable<T: TriggerInterface<T>>: TriggerInterface<T> {
     override fun triggerNow() = trigger(getThis())
 }

 class Test : Triggerable<Test>{
     override fun getThis(): Test = this

     override val trigger: (Test) -> Unit = { /*...*/ }
 }
```

Check http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ProgrammingIdioms.html#FAQ206

I would also personally recommend to reconsider if you really need both TriggerInterface AND Triggerable (where one inherits from the other).

Comment: It's needed because there is another interface which trigger another value

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's the best solution but not what I'm looking for. I ended using cast, because if the generic type argument "This" is well defined there will be no problem

Answer (score 0):

Calling `override fun triggerNow() = trigger(this as T)` you are trying to cast `Triggerable<T>` to `T` thats why compiler warns you about unchecked cast

having

```
    val trigger: (TriggerInterface<T>) -> Unit
```

will allow you to call trigger with no casting

```
    override fun triggerNow() = trigger(this)
```

to actually execute

```
override val trigger: (Test) -> Unit = { /*...*/ }
```

you need an instance of `Test` to pass inside of trigger which is not declared anywhere in your code yet